# Trying to multiply incredibly large exponents efficently and quickly

Tags: python-3.x, math

Im trying to multiply 2^82589933, however running this on python is very very very slow. Its been running for nearly 3 days and is not even 40% through the calculations, and is obviously slowing down exponentially. Being a python novice i have No idea on how to speed it up. I experimented with multi-threading, however i cannot see a reasonable way to multi-thread simple multiplication. Thanks for any help.

```py
import datetime
intg = 2
exp = 82589933
x = 0
for i in range(exp):
  intg = (intg * 2)
  x = x + 1
  if x == 100000:
    x = 0
    print(((i/exp)*100),'% - @',(datetime.datetime.now().time()))
    with open("log.txt", "a") as f:
      f.truncate(0)
      f.write(str(intg))
      f.write('\n')
      f.write(str(i))
with open("log.txt", "a") as f:
  f.truncate(0)
  f.write(str(intg))
  f.write('\n')
  f.write(str(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why having a text file containing 25 million decimal digits is going to be useful, but the only time-consuming part of the process is converting the integer to a string.  The actual *multiplication* is very quick, even on my underpowered notebook:

```
In [11]: %time result = 2**82589933
Wall time: 752 ms
```

Python's built-in utility to convert ints to strings is pretty good, but is just slow at this scale.  On my machine, we can roughly estimate it'd take 4-5 hours to convert the int to a string we could then write out:

```
In [13]: %time result = 10**10000; s = str(result)
Wall time: 2.99 ms

In [14]: %time result = 10**100000; s = str(result)
Wall time: 245 ms

In [15]: %time result = 10**1000000; s = str(result)
Wall time: 24.3 s

In [16]: 24.3 * (25**2) / 3600
Out[16]: 4.21875
```

One way to improve things would be to use a third-party library which has a faster int-to-string function, like [gmpy2](https://pypi.org/project/gmpy2/):

```
In [17]: import gmpy2

In [18]: %time r2 = gmpy2.mpz(2)**82589933
Wall time: 7.98 ms

In [19]: %time s = str(r2)
Wall time: 45.6 s

In [20]: s[:10]
Out[20]: '1488944457'

In [21]: len(s)
Out[21]: 24862048
```

which looks right:

```
In [23]: gmpy2.mpfr(2)**82589933
Out[23]: mpfr('1.4889444574204133e+24862047')
```

But again, say you write this to a text file.  What next?  We can't easily do arithmetic on a text file, and since the only thing of note about this number is that it's right next to the Mersenne prime 2^282,589,933-1, aren't you more interested in working with the number itself?  Serialization doesn't seem very interesting to me, but YMMV.

Comment: Your right i dont need it, but i thought, i like numbers, why not try and write a program that multiplies out the biggest prime number.

Answer (score -2):

In Python, to do powers of numbers you can use the `**` operator. So you don't need to write your own code: just type `2**82589933`.

However, the result of 2^82589933 equals an extremely high number, with thousands of digits, so the computer will take a lot of time to reach the result. The following number is the result of 2^10000, so imagine how long 2^82589933 will be.

19950631168807583848837421626835850838234968318861924548520089498529438830221946631919961684036194597899331129423209124271556491349413781117593785932096323957855730046793794526765246551266059895520550086918193311542508608460618104685509074866089624888090489894838009253941633257850621568309473902556912388065225096643874441046759871626985453222868538161694315775629640762836880760732228535091641476183956381458969463899410840960536267821064621427333394036525565649530603142680234969400335934316651459297773279665775606172582031407994198179607378245683762280037302885487251900834464581454650557929601414833921615734588139257095379769119277800826957735674444123062018757836325502728323789270710373802866393031428133241401624195671690574061419654342324638801248856147305207431992259611796250130992860241708340807605932320161268492288496255841312844061536738951487114256315111089745514203313820202931640957596464756010405845841566072044962867016515061920631004186422275908670900574606417856951911456055068251250406007519842261898059237118054444788072906395242548339221982707404473162376760846613033778706039803413197133493654622700563169937455508241780972810983291314403571877524768509857276937926433221599399876886660808368837838027643282775172273657572744784112294389733810861607423253291974813120197604178281965697475898164531258434135959862784130128185406283476649088690521047580882615823961985770122407044330583075869039319604603404973156583208672105913300903752823415539745394397715257455290510212310947321610753474825740775273986348298498340756937955646638621874569499279016572103701364433135817214311791398222983845847334440270964182851005072927748364550578634501100852987812389473928699540834346158807043959118985815145779177143619698728131459483783202081474982171858011389071228250905826817436220577475921417653715687725614904582904992461028630081535583308130101987675856234343538955409175623400844887526162643568648833519463720377293240094456246923254350400678027273837755376406726898636241037491410966718557050759098100246789880178271925953381282421954028302759408448955014676668389697996886241636313376393903373455801407636741877711055384225739499110186468219696581651485130494222369947714763069155468217682876200362777257723781365331611196811280792669481887201298643660768551639860534602297871557517947385246369446923087894265948217008051120322365496288169035739121368338393591756418733850510970271613915439590991598154654417336311656936031122249937969999226781732358023111862644575299135758175008199839236284615249881088960232244362173771618086357015468484058622329792853875623486556440536962622018963571028812361567512543338303270029097668650568557157505516727518899194129711337690149916181315171544007728650573189557450920330185304847113818315407324053319038462084036421763703911550639789000742853672196280903477974533320468368795868580237952218629120080742819551317948157624448298518461509704888027274721574688131594750409732115080498190455803416826949787141316063210686391511681774304792596709376

Comment: Yeah, Ik, however i found it normally just crashes, and is still way to slow.

Comment: With your edit, i am aware how long the number is but i need to calculate it.